# Добавление id к select2 jquery

Tags: html, jquery, select2

Библиотека select2, добавляет 5 значений в инпут, но остальные 4 значения не распознаются. Как добавлять эти 4 значения к 1-му инпуту?

Код:

`default.html:`

было 5 инпутов:

```
  <select id="val1" list="val" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="value1">
      {% for val in values %}
      <option value= "{{val}}" style="color: red;">{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <select id="val2" list="val" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="value2">
      {% for val in values %}
      <option value= "{{val}}" style="color: red;">{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <select id="val3" list="val" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="value3">
      {% for val in values %}
      <option value= "{{val}}" style="color: red;">{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <select id="val4" list="val" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="value4">
      {% for val in values %}
      <option value= "{{val}}" style="color: red;">{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <select id="val5" list="val" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="value5">
      {% for val in values %}
      <option value= "{{val}}" style="color: red;">{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

нужен(и стало) 1 input:

```
  <select id="val1" list="val" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="val1">
      {% for val in values %}
      <option value= "{{val}}" style="color: red;">{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

`js:`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#val1').select2();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#val2').select2();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#val3').select2();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#val4').select2();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#val5').select2();
});
```

Помогите решить. Спасибо.

Comment: Найти в вашей программе ваши инпуты, понять, что и как вводится,  понять причем библиотека select2 к расчету параметров - практически нереально. Декомпозируйте задачу.  Выделите код, который выполняет собственно обучение - в двух вариантах и покажите его тут.  Без всякого JS и HTML/ Желательно - в воспроизводимом виде, что-бы не пришлось делать web-запрос.  Тогда может быть кто-нибудь и захочет на досуге от нечего делать покопаться в ваших ошибках.

Comment: @passant, убрал лишнее. оставил нужное. посмотрите сейчас.

Comment: Так где у вас вариант, который вас устраивает и вариант, который вас не устраивает?

Comment: @passant обновил

Comment: На сколько я понял, библиотека select2 относиться к расширениям jQuery.

Comment: @passant, да, верно

Comment: Вы в тегах поставили "html", "Python 3.x", и даже "машинное обучение". Хорошо хоть не "нейронные сети".  Причем тут все это, если вопрос касается в худшем случае  JavaScript и jQuery, в лучшем "select2" ?  Измените теги, придут люди, сведущие в этих вопросах.  ответят

Comment: @passant, забыл изменить, минуту.